# Cannot pull multiple criteria via QUERY when enclosed in a LOWER(a) function

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, google-sheets-query

I am trying to get data from a Data range titled DealFinders. I have the columns I want to pull in via Query. I need to be able to pull using one Query function, multiple values that are run through a lower(##) function with the query.

Here's the code that works with the states listed as GA, ga, Ga, gA:

```
=IFERROR(
QUERY(
DealFinders, 
"select A,B,C,D,E,F,G,H,I,J,N,L,M,K,O,P,Q,R 
where
lower(L) contains lower('GA') order by R, 0"),
"No Results")
```

---

```
=IFERROR(
QUERY(
DealFinders, 
"select A,B,C,D,E,F,G,H,I,J,N,L,M,K,O,P,Q,R 
where
" lower(L) contains lower('GA') order by R, 0 " & " AND " & "
  lower(L) contains lower('NC') order by R, 0 ""),"No Results")
```

The query should show all the people who are in the states GA (Georgia) or NC (North Carolina).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try it like this:

```
=IFERROR(QUERY(DealFinders, 
 "select A,B,C,D,E,F,G,H,I,J,N,L,M,K,O,P,Q,R 
  where lower(L) contains 'ga' 
     or lower(L) contains 'nc' order by R", 0), "No Results")
```

Comment: That worked. Any way to pull the abbreviations in as UPPERCASE? That would be the K column.

Comment: sure. the command is `upper()` - https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/querylanguage